# How to calculate closest highest nearest number in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

suppose i have array of number like

```
00
05
10
15
upto
55
```

now i want to develop a routine where i will pass the array and a input number.
suppose i pass 32 as input so 32 will be search in
array and return 35 Because 35 is closest highest nearest of 32. So just guide me how to develop like that routine.

here i develop one which is returning 30 as closest of 32 but i want 35 should be return. i know there is some flaw in routine. it would help if some one help me to construct right routine.

here is mine which is not returning expected result.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
            var array = [00, 05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55];
            var number = 32;
            alert (closest (number, array)); // display output here

        function closest (num, arr) {
                var curr = arr[0];
                var diff = Math.abs (num - curr);
                for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
                    var newdiff = Math.abs (num - arr[val]);
                    if (newdiff < diff) {
                        diff = newdiff;
                        curr = arr[val];
                    }
                }
                curr=(curr>=10)?curr:'0'+curr;  //If result is 5, to display '05' instead of '5'
                return curr;
            }
});
</script>
```

thanks

### I will accept this one

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var array = [00, 05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55];
        test(32)
        test(4)
        test(100)
        test(47)
        test(45)

        function test(num) {
            //log(num + ' --> ' + closest(num, array)); // display output here
            alert(closest(num, array));
        }

        function closest(num, arr) {
            var curr = Infinity;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] >= num && curr > arr[i]) {
                    curr = arr[i]
                }
            }
            curr = (curr >= 10) ? curr : '0' + curr; //If result is 5, to display '05' instead of '5'
            return curr;
        }
    });

    var log = (function () {
        var $log = $('#log');
        return function (msg) {
            $('<p/>', {
                text: msg
            }).prependTo($log)
        }
    })();
```

Comment: Why not simply insert it into the array, sort it in ascending order, get the index of the inserting string. The closest and larger number would be at index + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/59n6f5qv/1/

**UPDATE:**

```
var array = [00, 05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55];
var number = 32;
alert(closest(number, array)); // display output here


function closest(num, arr) {    
    var next = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);


    for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
        if (arr[val] >= number && arr[val] < next) next = arr[val];        
    }    

    curr = next;

    curr = (curr >= 10) ? curr : '0' + curr; //If result is 5, to display '05' instead of '5'
    return curr;
}
```

Comment: your routine is returning 45 when input is 46 but i want 50 should be return because 50 is closest highest of 46.

Comment: I did not read the question until the end :) please see update

Comment: can u tell me how to convert a dropdown or combobox value to array ? if possible then give me a sample code. thanks

Comment: i tried this but no luck `        function selectToArray(targetid) {
            var $target = $("select[id*=" + targetid + "] option");
            var arr = [];
            $target.each(function () {
                arr.push($(this).val())
            })

            return arr;
        }
        var newArray = selectToArray('DropDownList1');
        alert(newArray);`

Comment: can u tell me how to attach one onchange event for multiple dropdown and also like to get dropdown id from onchange event. if u know then please help me with sample code. thanks

Comment: select to Array: http://jsfiddle.net/h0j81fw3/3/ proper use of the id selector is: #{targetid} eg. $('#combobox')

Comment: can u tell me how to attach one onchange event for multiple dropdown and also like to get dropdown id from onchange event. if u know then please help me with sample code. thanks

Comment: what is the meaning of this line `var next = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);` ?

Comment: finds the highest value in array

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = [00, 05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55];
  test(32)
  test(4)
  test(100)
  test(47)
  test(45)

  function test(num) {
    log(num + ' --> ' + closest(num, array)); // display output here
  }

  function closest(num, arr) {
    var curr = Infinity;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] >= num && curr > arr[i]) {
        curr = arr[i]
      }
    }
    curr = (curr >= 10) ? curr : '0' + curr; //If result is 5, to display '05' instead of '5'
    return curr;
  }
});

var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).prependTo($log)
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: it is bit ok but still there is a problem. when i test with 30 then it is giving 35 which is not right because 30 is there in array. so when i would test with the value that is presented in array then that value should be return. so plzz edit your code a bit.

Comment: plzz do a little change when input value is more than 55 then 55 should be return. your routine return infinity when input is 100 but i want when input is 100 then 55 should be return value 55 is the highest value in array. so make a little edit in your routine if possible. thanks

Comment: @Mou whether the array will always be sorted

Comment: can u tell me how to convert a dropdown or combobox value to array ? if possible then give me a sample code. thanks

Comment: how do u include run code snippet feature in your answer. please tell me what i need to do so from the next time when i put any question or answer then i could also provide that kind of feature along with my question or answer so other can see and run the code.thanks

Comment: @Mou in the post edit view, in the toolbar above the textarea you have a board and pencil icon which is used to create the code snippet - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1):

Fast `(O(n))` and simple enough.

This approach gets the exact and nearest values. Low, Exact and High.

```js
var max = function (arr) { return  Math.max.apply(null, arr); };
var min = function (arr) { return  Math.min.apply(null, arr); };
    
var nearest  = function (arr, x) {
    var l = [], h = [];
    var exact = -1;
    
    arr.forEach(function (v) {           
       if (v == x) exact = v;
       ((v < x) && l.push(v)) || ((v > x) && h.push(v));
    });
       
    return { "low": arr.indexOf(max(l)), "exact": exact, "high": arr.indexOf(min(h)) };
};

var array = [00, 05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55];
 
var testValue = 30;

var range = nearest(array, testValue);

if (range.exact != -1) {
     alert("Exact Value " + testValue) 
}
alert("Near Low:" + array[range.low] + " Near High:" + array[range.high]);
```

Comment: how do u include run code snippet feature in your answer. please tell me what i need to do so from the next time when i put any question or answer then i could also provide that kind of feature along with my question or answer so other can see and run the code.thanks

Comment: @mou easy, on editor press Ctrl-M or click the button which tooltip say "Code Snippet", BTW please support [this feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278311/add-resources-to-code-snippet)

Answer (score 0):

```
function closest(num, arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0) { throw ("Array is empty"); }
    if (arr[0] > actualnum) { return arr[0]; }
    var diff = actualnum - arr[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (actualnum <= arr[i]) {
            return (arr[i] - actualnum > diff) ? arr[i - 1] : arr[i];
        } else {
        diff = actualnum - arr[i];
        }
    }
    return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```